# 80s possibly 90s anime with a transformation involving a red outfit and an expanding chest

Tags: story-identification, anime

This will be difficult because it was only roughly 5 seconds worth of content.

I'm looking for a show that featured a nighttime cityscape backdrop and an anime transformation sequence which ended with the girl's chest size growing exponentially. I believe she was wearing red, but other than your typical Sailor Moon type style of song and spinning that's the only thing than I can remember because right after the boobs thing, my mom walked in the room and I had to slam the change channels button.

But it's haunted me for years.

It was a re run of an old show. Very late at night, it was in English on a channel that did not typically have cartoons

Comment: My first thought is Aki, of Tekkaman Blade, but I figure you would have mentioned the giant robot.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: I'm gonna add it to the list of stuff to check out. I only saw the 5 second transformation sequence.

Comment: Here is a video that shows openings  of animes that deal with magical girl and most of the magical girls have transformations. Maybe you might recognize the girl. It sounds like you either saw an opening or just a part of the transformation. Maybe with more detalis, it would be easier to identify. Red is a favorite color to use for females in anime.  https://youtu.be/p4VqKBEjomU

Comment: I’m just going to say “anime growing boobs” will give thousands of results. Has any adult show NOT done this? I’m saying it needs more detail

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is right now, since there's no spinning, and the breast expansion is hardly exponential, but here's a shot: was she blonde? The thing that popped into my head immediately was *Dirty Pair Flash*. It's early '90s, Kei wears red, and her transformation scene looks like breast expansion (though I found a YouTube clip and it's more that her cloths change to push them up):

*Devil Hunter Yohko* also involves a girl in red with a spinning transformation scene but no breast expansion.